# GroupBy and Transform does not keep all columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I am having the following dataset:

```
Stock_id    Week    Stock_value
1   1   2
1   2   4
1   4   7
1   5   1
2   3   8
2   4   6
2   5   5
2   6   3
```

I want to shift the values of the `Stock_value` column by one position so that I get the following:

```
Stock_id    Week    Stock_value
1   1   NA
1   2   2
1   4   4
1   5   7
2   3   NA
2   4   8
2   5   6
2   6   5
```

What I am doing is the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.txt', keep_default_na=True, sep='\t')

df = df.groupby('Store_id', as_index=False)['Waiting_time'].transform(lambda x:x.shift(periods=1))
```

But then this gives me:

```
   Waiting_time
0           NaN
1           2.0
2           4.0
3           7.0
4           NaN
5           8.0
6           6.0
7           5.0
```

So it gives me the values shifted but it does not retain all the columns of the dataframe.

How do I also retain all the columns of the dataframe along with shifting the values of one column?

Comment: Need `df['new col'] = df.groupby('Store_id...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify solution by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and assign back to new column:

```
df['Waiting_time'] = df.groupby('Stock_id')['Stock_value'].shift()
```

Working same like:

```
df['Waiting_time']=df.groupby('Stock_id')['Stock_value'].transform(lambda x:x.shift(periods=1))

print (df)
   Stock_id  Week  Stock_value  Waiting_time
0         1     1            2           NaN
1         1     2            4           2.0
2         1     4            7           4.0
3         1     5            1           7.0
4         2     3            8           NaN
5         2     4            6           8.0
6         2     5            5           6.0
7         2     6            3           5.0
```

Comment: Ok this works and it is even better for me (upvote). Thank you. However, to be honest  with you, I am a little bit confused with if columns are retained after using `.transform`, `.apply()`...in my eyes every time something different is happening...haha...

Comment: @PoeteMaudit - yes, if check [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) docs, then are some `must`, so there should be some difference if use some custom functions.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `df.groupby('Store_id', as_index=False)['Waiting_time']`, you obtain a DataFrame with a single column 'Waiting_time', you can't generate the other columns from that.

As suggested by jezrael in the comment, you should do

```
df['new col'] = df.groupby('Store_id...
```

to add this new column to your previously existing DataFrame.